# Swift Decodable issue - Trouble assigning value to an array

Tags: ios, json, swift, decodable

I'm having trouble troubleshooting this error at **self.tvShows = shows.data**

I get the error **Cannot assign value of type 'RecentTvListDays' to type '[TvShowDetails]?'**

I've attached the JSON structure as an image at the bottom. Hope this is enough.

```
class TvHomeController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout    {

fileprivate let cellId = "cellId"

var tvShows: [TvShowDetails]? = []

func fetchTvItems()   {

    let jsonUrlString = "https://www.what-song.com/api/air-episodes"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else
    {return}

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

        guard let data = data else {return}

        do {

            let shows =  try
                JSONDecoder().decode(RecentTvListData.self, from: data)

            self.tvShows = shows.data

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }

        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing JSON", jsonErr)
        }

        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Model

```
import UIKit

struct RecentTvListData: Decodable  {
var data: RecentTvListDays
}

struct RecentTvListDays: Decodable {
var RecentTvListByDay: [TvShowDetails]
}

struct TvShowDetails: Decodable   {
var _id: Int
var name: String
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your parse a `shows` constant is of the type `RecentTVListData`. Then you are attempting to set your array of `TvShowDetails` to be the RecentTVListData's data (RecentTvListDays).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're almost there, actually. I believe you simply need to change one line:

```
self.tvShows = shows.data.RecentTvListByDay
```

Like I mention in the comments, you're simply trying to set to a different type (like the error says, really).

Side-note/tip: always start your variable- and property-names with lowercase. (Conforms to conventions and improves readability).

Comment: Arn't Structs and Classes meant to start with capital letters? Or have I been misinformed..

Comment: No, you have not been misinformed. You are however mixing properties/variables with _types_ . When defining the struct `RecentTvListDays` you should definitely begin with a capital. However, when you define this struct's _property_ (var) `recentTVListsByDay` it should be lower-case. I frankly have some issues with your naming in general, but I'll save that for another time. ;-)

Comment: Actually, my very last comment wasn't particularly helpful. I've created a gist to show what I'm talking about: https://gist.github.com/nickfalk/f9dba91d54b89edbbbbac959b3262b45

Comment: Ahhhh yes, you're 100% correct. I see what you mean. I will adopt this across my classes now :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear, a type mismatch. Look at your code:

- The data source array `tvShows` is declared as **`[TvShowDetails]?`**
- The result of the property `data` in the decoded struct is **`RecentTvListDays`**

The types are different. That's exactly what the error message

> Cannot assign value of type 'RecentTvListDays' to type '[TvShowDetails]?

tells you. According to the JSON structure you have to assign

```
let shows =  try JSONDecoder().decode(RecentTvListData.self, from: data)
self.tvShows = shows.data.RecentTvListByDay
```

Comment: Omg! I can't believe it was that simple. I was going up and down for ages. Thanks so much!